# Where is Android executable snap path in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework, path, haskell-snap-framework

I need to find **Android executable path** for my Ionic Apps, I have Android installed with **snap** in Ubuntu, and in Glances result I can read this :

```
 PID 302   /snap/android-studio/84/android-studio/jre/bin/java -classpath
```

But these folders are empty, the command line is :

> npx cap open android

And I get this :

```
[info] Opening Android project at /home/phobos/dev2/reactjs/iotabreact/android
[error] Unable to launch Android Studio. You must configure "linuxAndroidStudioPath" in your capacitor.config.json to point to the location of studio.sh, using JavaScript-escaped paths:
Example:
{
  "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

I found it now :

```
"linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/snap/bin/android-studio",
```

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 8):

Next time use `which app_name` to find any app path e.g. `which android-studio`